# No video only sound, when using invidious

Tags: web-browser

I freshly installed elementary OS. I've tried using invidious in  the default browser and only sound played but there was no video. Tried some other instances and the same problem occured.

Comment: You may want to [file a bug](https://github.com/iv-org/invidious/issues) with the developers of Invidious 

Answer (score 0):

Has this been resolved. I have just installed Elementary OS 6.1, installed restricted codecs, video doesn't work in default player. Installed VLC and it works. So what's the problem with the default player?